Subindex sorted by occurrence
In a mathematical document, I have several indices. As I am not a LaTeX programmer I have no idea how to make only the symbol index to be sorted by occurrence. The question Symbol index sorted by occurrence
seems to work for the complete index only, not for a subindex.
Can anyone help?
Minimal example:
\documentclass{scrbook}
%\usepackage[backend=biber, style=authortitle-comp]{biblatex}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{imakeidx}
\makeindex
\makeindex[name=s,title={Symbole}]

\begin{document}
    
\title{\Huge Grundlagen der Analysis}
\author{Heinz König}
\date{}
\publishers{herausgegeben von *** und ***}
\maketitle

\lipsum[10]
\index{Folge!Funktionenfolge}
\index{Folge!Zahlenfolge}
\index{Konvergenz}
\index[s]{$\subset$}    
\index[s]{$\notin$} 
    
\newpage
\lipsum[30]
\index{Differenzierbare Mannigfaltigkeit}
\index{Reelle Zahl}
\index[s]{$\in$}    

\newpage
\lipsum[10]
\index{Gleichmäßig stetig}
\index[s]{$\lim$}   

\newpage
\lipsum[10]
\index[s]{$\cap$}   
\index[s]{$\mathbb{N}$}

\newpage    
\lipsum[10]
\index{Limes inferior}
\index[s]{$\cup$}   
\index[s]{$\mathbb{Z}$}

\newpage
\lipsum[10]
\index{Endliches Maß}
\index[s]{$\inf$}   
\index[s]{$\mathbb{R}$}

\newpage
\lipsum[10]
\index{Häufungspunkt}
\index[s]{@$\mathbb{C}$}

\newpage    
\lipsum[10] 
\index[s]{$\sup$}
\index[s]{$\nu$}

\newpage
\index[s]{$\kappa$} 

\printindex[s]
\printindex

    
\end{document}

This gives:

but I want to have - without changing the usual sorting of the wordindex:


Welcome to TeX.SE! Well, without seeing any code it is hard or impossible to help you. Please show us a short compilable TeX code resulting in your issue! Then we do not have to guess what you are doing ...

See  symlist   on this page  https://personal.utdallas.edu/~hamlen/projects.html

Minimal example of status quo:

yannisl: thanks for the symlist suggestion. Have you any idea how to modify the approach to get 2 columns and do away with the dots?

You can use the @ feature of \index. If your index entries are
\index[symbols]{1@$\subset$}
\index[symbols]{2@$\notin$}

and so on, they will be indexed according to the number preceding @. The number can be automatically generated.
You can also simplify the input by omitting the $ symbols.
\documentclass{scrbook}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{imakeidx}
\makeindex
\makeindex[name=symbols,title={Symbole}]

\newcounter{symindex}
\newcommand{\symindex}[1]{%
  \stepcounter{symindex}%
  \index[symbols]{\thesymindex@\unexpanded{$#1$}}%
}

\begin{document}
    
\title{\Huge Grundlagen der Analysis}
\author{Heinz König}
\date{}
\publishers{herausgegeben von *** und ***}
\maketitle

\lipsum[10]
\index{Folge!Funktionenfolge}
\index{Folge!Zahlenfolge}
\index{Konvergenz}
\symindex{\subset}
\symindex{\notin}

\newpage
\lipsum[30]
\index{Differenzierbare Mannigfaltigkeit}
\index{Reelle Zahl}
\symindex{\in}

\newpage
\lipsum[10]
\index{Gleichmäßig stetig}
\symindex{\lim}

\newpage
\lipsum[10]
\symindex{\cap}
\symindex{\mathbb{N}}

\newpage
\lipsum[10]
\index{Limes inferior}
\symindex{\cup}
\symindex{\mathbb{Z}}

\newpage
\lipsum[10]
\index{Endliches Maß}
\symindex{\inf}
\symindex{\mathbb{R}}

\newpage
\lipsum[10]
\index{Häufungspunkt}
\symindex{\mathbb{C}}

\newpage
\lipsum[10]
\symindex{\sup}
\symindex{\nu}

\newpage
\lipsum[11]
\symindex{\kappa}

\printindex[symbols]
\printindex

\end{document}


A possibly better implementation, but the same conceptually:
\documentclass{scrbook}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{imakeidx}
\makeindex
\makeindex[name=symbols,title={Symbole}]

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand{\symindex}{m}
 {
  \reiner_symindex:Ve \g_reiner_symindex_int { \tl_to_str:n { #1 } }
 }

\int_new:N \g_reiner_symindex_int

\cs_new_protected:Nn \reiner_symindex:nn
 {
  \int_gincr:N \g_reiner_symindex_int
  \index[symbols]{#1@$#2$}
 }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \reiner_symindex:nn { Ve }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
    
\title{\Huge Grundlagen der Analysis}
\author{Heinz König}
\date{}
\publishers{herausgegeben von *** und ***}
\maketitle

\lipsum[10]
\index{Folge!Funktionenfolge}
\index{Folge!Zahlenfolge}
\index{Konvergenz}
\symindex{\subset}
\symindex{\notin}

\newpage
\lipsum[30]
\index{Differenzierbare Mannigfaltigkeit}
\index{Reelle Zahl}
\symindex{\in}

\newpage
\lipsum[10]
\index{Gleichmäßig stetig}
\symindex{\lim}

\newpage
\lipsum[10]
\symindex{\cap}
\symindex{\mathbb{N}}

\newpage
\lipsum[10]
\index{Limes inferior}
\symindex{\cup}
\symindex{\mathbb{Z}}

\newpage
\lipsum[10]
\index{Endliches Maß}
\symindex{\inf}
\symindex{\mathbb{R}}

\newpage
\lipsum[10]
\index{Häufungspunkt}
\symindex{\mathbb{C}}

\newpage
\lipsum[10]
\symindex{\sup}
\symindex{\nu}

\newpage
\lipsum[11]
\symindex{\kappa}

\printindex[symbols]
\printindex

\end{document}

(I'd avoid using s for the file name associated to the index.)

Solved, using yannisl's suggestion.
\documentclass{scrbook}
%\usepackage[backend=biber, style=authortitle-comp]{biblatex}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\usepackage{symlist}
\setlength\columnsep{30pt}

\usepackage{imakeidx}
\makeindex
\makeindex[name=s,title={Symbole}]

\begin{document}
    
    \title{\Huge Grundlagen der Analysis}
    \author{Heinz König}
    \date{}
    \publishers{herausgegeben von *** und ***}
    \maketitle
    
    \lipsum[10]
    \index{Folge!Funktionenfolge}
    \index{Folge!Zahlenfolge}
    \index{Konvergenz}
    \newsym{}{$\subset$}    
    \newsym{}{$\notin$} 
    
    \newpage
    \lipsum[30]
    \index{Differenzierbare Mannigfaltigkeit}
    \index{Reelle Zahl}
    \newsym{}{$\in$}    
    
    \newpage
    \lipsum[10]
    \index{Gleichmäßig stetig}
    \newsym{}{$\lim$}   
    
    \newpage
    \lipsum[10]
    \newsym{}{$\cap$}   
    \newsym{}{$\mathbb{N}$}
    
    \newpage    
    \lipsum[10]
    \index{Limes inferior}
    \newsym{}{$\cup$}   
    \newsym{}{$\mathbb{Z}$}
    
    \newpage
    \lipsum[10]
    \index{Endliches Maß}
    \newsym{}{$\inf$}   
    \newsym{}{$\mathbb{R}$}
    
    \newpage
    \lipsum[10]
    \index{Häufungspunkt}
    \newsym{}{$\mathbb{C}$}
    
    \newpage    
    \lipsum[10] 
    \newsym{}{$\sup$}
    \newsym{}{$\nu$}
    
    \newpage
    \newsym{}{$\kappa$} 
    
    \listofsymbols
    \printindex
    
    
\end{document}

and modifying the symlist package fom https://personal.utdallas.edu/~hamlen/symlist.sty
%%
%% This is file `symlist.sty',
%% generated with the docstrip utility.
%%
%% The original source files were:
%%
%% symlist.dtx  (with options: `package')
%% 
%% This is a generated file.
%% 
%% Copyright (C) 2008 by Kevin W. Hamlen
%% 
%% This file may be distributed and/or modified under the conditions of
%% the LaTeX Project Public License, either version 1.3a of this license
%% or (at your option) any later version.  The latest version of this
%% license is in:
%% 
%%    http://www.latex-project.org/lppl.txt
%% 
%% and version 1.3a or later is part of all distributions of LaTeX version
%% 2004/10/01 or later.
%% 
\usepackage{multicol}%modified
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesPackage{symlist}
  [2008/03/11 v1.1 Symbol List package]
\ProcessOptions\relax
\newcommand\LOS@symline[4]{%
  \ifx\hyper@anchor\@undefined%
    \contentsline{symbol}{\numberline{#2}{#3}}{#4}\relax%
  \else%
    \contentsline{symbol}{\numberline{#2}{#3}}{#4}{symbol.#1}%
  \fi%
}
\renewcommand{\@dotsep}{10000}%modified
\newcommand\listsymbolname{Liste der Symbole}
\newcount\LOS@cnt
\newdimen\LOS@wd
\newcommand\LOS@ext{los}
\newcommand\LOS@init[1]{%
  \long\gdef\l@symbol{\@dottedtocline{1}{0em}{#1}}%
}
\newcommand\newsym{\@ifnextchar[\LOS@@newsym\LOS@newsym}
\newcommand\LOS@newsym[2]{\LOS@@newsym[#2]{#1}{#2}}
\newcommand\LOS@@newsym{}
\def\LOS@@newsym[#1]#2#3{%
  \global\advance\LOS@cnt\@ne%
  \ifmmode%
    \settowidth\dimen@{$#1$\kern1em}%
    \expandafter\gdef%
      \csname LOS@sym@\romannumeral\LOS@cnt\endcsname##1##2{%
      \@writefile\LOS@ext{\LOS@symline{##1}{$#1$}{#2}{##2}}}%
  \else%
    \settowidth\dimen@{#1\kern1em}%
    \expandafter\gdef%
      \csname LOS@sym@\romannumeral\LOS@cnt\endcsname##1##2{%
      \@writefile\LOS@ext{\LOS@symline{##1}{#1}{#2}{##2}}}%
  \fi%
  \ifdim\dimen@>\LOS@wd\global\LOS@wd\dimen@\fi%
  \if@filesw%
    \write\expandafter\@auxout\expandafter{%
      \expandafter\noexpand\expandafter\LOS@sym\expandafter{%
      \romannumeral\LOS@cnt}{\thepage}}%
  \fi%
  \@ifundefined{hyperdef}{}%
    {\hyperdef{symbol}{\romannumeral\LOS@cnt}}%
  {#3}%
}
\newcommand\LOS@sym[2]{}
\AtBeginDocument{%
  \gdef\LOS@sym#1{\csname LOS@sym@#1\endcsname{#1}}%
  \if@filesw%
    \@temptokena{\expandafter\@writefile\expandafter\LOS@ext%
      \expandafter{\expandafter\LOS@init\expandafter{\the\LOS@wd}}}%
    \immediate\write\@auxout{\the\@temptokena}%
  \fi%
}
%modified
\ifx\chapter\undefined
  \newcommand\listofsymbols{%
    \section*{\listsymbolname}%
    \addvspace{10\p@}%
    \begin{multicols}{2}
        \@starttoc\LOS@ext%
    \end{multicols}
  }
\else
  \newcommand\listofsymbols{%    
    \chapter*{\listsymbolname}%
    \addvspace{15\p@}%
    \begin{multicols}{2}
        \@starttoc\LOS@ext%
    \end{multicols}
  }
\fi
\endinput
%%
%% End of file `symlist.sty'.

Thanks for your help!
